# Notação de limites desestruturada quando está em um expoente

Tags: latex

Estou com dificuldades em fazer com que a função  \lim_{x \to \infty}  fique no expoente estruturada de maneira que o  {x \to \infty}   fique embaixo e não do lado de 'lim'. Isso só acontece quando coloco o limite no expoente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
e ^ { \lim_{x \to + \infty} \left(  { \ln \left( \dfrac{2x +3 }{2x + 1} \right) \  \cdot   \ x } \right)  }
```

O resultado é estranho e de difícil entendimento.

(Quando está normal -lembrando que isso não acontece quando está no expoente- )

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
\lim_{x \to + \infty}  \left( e ^ { \ln \left( \dfrac{2x +3 }{2x + 1} \right) \  \cdot   \ x } \right)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\limits` logo após `\lim`:

```
e^{ \lim\limits_{x \to + \infty} \left( { \ln \left( \dfrac{2x +3 }{2x + 1} \right) \cdot   \ x } \right) }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Particularmente, quando o expoente é complicado como este, prefiro utilizar a notação `\exp`, mas é só questão de estilo mesmo:

```
\exp \left( \lim_{x \to + \infty} { \ln \left( \dfrac{2x +3 }{2x + 1} \right) \  \cdot   \ x } \right) }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Valeuzão mesmo, na pressa até tinha esquecido que poderia usar o exp é uma boa alternativa

Comment: É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.